# Angular JS Ng-Repeat Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario like I want to display the contents which are available in only one array, if its present in another array there is no need to display it.

My html is like

```
<div ng-repeat="array1Value in array1">
    <div ng-repeat="array2Value in array2">
        <div ng-if="isNotFound(array1,array2Value.id)">
            <span>{{array2Value.name}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My js class is like

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp",{});

app.controller("MyController",function($scope) {
    $scope.array1 = [
        {
            id:"1",name:"one"
        },
        {
            id:"2",name:"two"
        },
        {
            id:"3",name:"three"
        }
    ];

    $scope.array2 = [
        {
            id:"1",name:"one"
        },
        {
            id:"2",name:"two"
        },
        {
            id:"4",name:"four"
        }
    ];

    $scope.alreadyPrinted = [{}];

    $scope.isNotFound = function(array,value){
        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if (value === array[i].id) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if($scope.alreadyPrinted.indexOf(value) > -1){
            return false;
        } else {   
            $scope.alreadyPrinted.push(value);
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

I need only four as my output. But as of now nothing is coming. Please help me to correct the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove external loop... try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="array2Value in array2">
    <div ng-if="isNotFound(array1,array2Value.id)">
        <span>{{array2Value.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want True to be returned if the value is not in the first array.

Try this for your isnotFound function:

```
$scope.isNotFound = function(array,value){
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (value !== array[i].id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return fase;
}
```

Or maybe even better:

```
$scope.isNotFound = function(array,value){
    angular.forEach(array, function(item){
        if (value !== item.id) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return fase; 
}
```

I'm not sure why you are repeating over the first array and the allreadyPrinted part. Your html can just be:

```
<div ng-repeat="array2Value in array2">
    <div ng-if="isNotFound(array1,array2Value.id)">
        <span>{{array2Value.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem in your alreadyPrinted code. Your code is displaying 'four' as output. Try to insert one alert box in your code like

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (value === array[i].id) {
        alert('is not found function called');
        return false;
    }
}
```

You will see 'four' as output on your browser but for one iteration only.
Correct your alreadyPrinted code.alert box will help you to isolate the problem.